# Handle Bulk insertion in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using table type for bulk insertion or updating, but I am unable to deal with the case a single error in 100 records. In that case for one entry my 99 entries will fail what to do in that case?

Comment: What defines "invalid" in your case? Any chance to not select for update in that case?

Comment: @Jan invalid means if i have entered wrong date like 1/1/10001 etc,,taking any approx execption here..so in result my 99 enteries are not going to update due to one wrong entry..i want to update all valid enteries accept the faulty one transaction

Comment: Please give more info like : the error message, Table structure, insert and update command...

Comment: @Msfvtp i am assuming or you can say a test case in mind .. i dont have any concrete error..it may be any like i passed overflow value that specified value like varchar(50)..but i am passing 60..now you are getting me or not ?

Comment: Tried to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can commit for update commands after each update operation and use **insert ignore into** instead of **insert into** command for insertion and commit in the end. For better performance on insert you can use mysql specific syntax :

```
insert ignore into t1(a,b) values (1,2),(3,4),(5,6);
```

Comment: @stylishCoder you can commit after each update command. It may slow down operation but I don't have other solution now.